# Traverse directory tree & print poorly-named files

Tags: bash

If I call this function with ./usr and have a poorly-named file called meowmeowmeow11 under some subdirectory. How can I just output /usr/cat/meowmeowmeow111 and not the full path.

```
func() {
names=`ls -A $1 | sort`

for name in $names
do 
    if [[ -d $name ]]; then
        if [ -r $name ]; then
            cd $name
            func "."
            cd ..
        else
            echo "Lack of permission to read a subdirectory."
        fi
    else
        if [[ ${#name} -gt 14 ]]; then  // Check if name is over 14 characters
            realpath $name // Not sure
        fi
    fi
done
}
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: What do you want it to output? isn't `/usr/cat/meowmeowmeow111` already the full path?

Comment: Ex: If I pass in ./func ./lab1/lab2. I should return /lab1/lab/meowmeowmeow111 not the full path from the root